# Automatically scrolls up after loading more items (Endless scrolling)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to implement an endless scrolling in RoR but after it loads more items, automatically scrolls to the top of the page. I want to keep the same position. What could be happening?

Controller:

```
def index
  @works = Work.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15).order('created_at DESC')
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

View index.js.erb:

```
$("#works").append('<%= j render("work_page_header") %>');
$("#works").append('<%= j render(@works) %>');

<% if @works.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@works) %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

endless_scrolling.js:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() { 
  if( $('.pagination').length && $('#works-list').length)

  $(window).on('scroll', function(e){
    var url = $('.pagination .page-link[rel="next"]').attr('href');

    if(url && $(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50)) {
      $('.pagination').text('Loading works...');
      $.getScript(url);
      console.log('paginate...', url);
      $(window).scroll();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function did the trick in place of: `$(window).scroll()`
I put

```
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() - 
$(window).height() }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).animate({ scrollBottom: 0 }, 1000);
  });
```